# Visual studio 2010 debugger don't stop at Breakpoint?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, breakpoints

I've problem using visual studio 2010 on my computer (windows 7 64-bits)

I'm doing a c# add-in for outlook. I could add it on outlook, try it, but I couldn't debug it because debugger don't stop at breakpoints. I search something about that on google and here, but I found nothing that help me.

Someone have a solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you attached Visual Studio to the Outlook process?
To attach to an existing process open Debug->Attach to Process...

Then you should be able to debug your own code.

Edit:
Have a look at [this](http://freetodev.wordpress.com/2010/03/05/debugging-outlook-2010-add-ins-with-visual-studio-2010/). Basically there seem to be two ways this could be resolved:

- Change your project start action to Start Project instead of Start external app
- There's another link in that article pointing to [another post](http://blogs.msdn.com/mshneer/archive/2010/03/19/com-shim-wizards-for-vs-2010.aspx). In that is quite a lot of stuff, but at the bottom there's descriped that VS can't debug multiple Frameworks at the same time (like 2.0 and 4.0). There are also some descriptions at how to work around this.

Comment: I couldn't do that. When I selected Outlook, "attach" couldn't be selected

Comment: Is there already some debugger attached to outlook? I just had a quick look and could attach to any process on my system. Only time I know of that you can't attach is when the process already has a debugger attached. Have you checked the type of attachment? Default should be automatic, you can try setting it explicitly to managed.

Comment: Also if you are already attached to Outlook you have to make sure that the assembly used by Outlook is the exact same version you have in Visual Studio. VS won't break when the code base is different. Well, you can override this, but I forgot where exactly this option was. Anyway this usually won't help because different code bases make debugging nearly impossible most of the times.

Comment: In fact my problem is not to launch the debugger but that the debugger don't stop to the breakpoint. 
When I do "F5" outlook open with my add-in but never stop where i put break

Comment: Ok, so you're already attached to outlook, that's good.
Are you sure that line of code is executed? Maybe try some other line that is sure to be executed and see if that works.
Also is the Breakpoint at runtime displayed normal or just lined out? If it's lined out it means either the assembly is not loaded yet or the CodeBase doesn't match. If the Breakpoint is outlined and your code is surely executed then have a look at the context menu for the breakpoint, I think there should be an option to ignore differing code bases.

Comment: yes, I'm sure that the line is executed. 

Sorry but I don't understand what you mean by " Also is the Breakpoint at runtime displayed normal or just lined out?" ? (I'm French, and very bad in English)

Comment: During design time and while debugging only if the breakpoint is active/valid it is normally shown with red background (depending on your settings). If a breakpoint could not be bound VS displays it a little different, usually only with a red rectangle (outlined) instead of a red background.

Comment: OK, yes the line have red background and there is a red point on merge.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Unfortunately when I do that and click "F5" I have a message error that say "ou cannot debug or run this project because the required version of the Microsoft office is not installed".Of course I have installed Office without any problem so it isn't that

Comment: What version of Office are you using? Have you tried the second possibility concerning different Frameworks?

Comment: I used Office Pro 2007. For the second link, yes I tried, I could launch addin but breakpoint are not hit again.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same issue in Visual Studio 2012.

I genuinely literally just added `MessageBox.Show("test");` into `private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e) { }` and the breakpoints that were already in existence were hit.

The cause of the original difficulty was the first time I experience an exception.  Potentially the thread didn't exit cleanly and run auto generated finally and Shutdown methods.