# VS 2010 is ignoring break points

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I've got some breakpoints in Visual Studio, and whilst debugging in debug mode, they are being ignored.

This only occurs when variable is not used. EG

```
 string s = "10;
 string t = "Hi";
 return s;
```

In the above, it will not stop if I set a break point on the `string t`. Nor will it show 't' in the debug window. If I set a watch, the message in the Watch Window is

> The name 't' does not exist in the current context

What I'm having to do as a work around is

```
 string s = "10;
 string t = "Hi";
 string z = t; //pointless but the compiler now let's me focus on it
 return s;
```

Please note, this happens for all variables throughout the entire program.

My own research suggests it's the JIT doing this; that it is optimizing the code for me and removing any overhead where it can, but I thought it would only do this in release mode? The point of me doing the above is so I can compare a new value against an old value as I'm re-factoring code.

My question is, can I turn off this compiler optimization?

This [Visual studio 2010 debugger don't stop at Breakpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089913/visual-studio-2010-debugger-dont-stop-at-breakpoint) doesn't help.

All projects are .NET 4.0  (I know having different versions .NET can confuse the compiler)
Within the solution configruation, I have debug selected
In the Properties Window -> Debug is also set for Debug
In the Properties Window -> Build, has Optimize code unchecked

Comment: You are right, the compiler will even give you a warning about this, and that code will not be part of the generated IL.

Comment: Have you searched for this on SO's other posts regarding this?

Comment: I did a search, hence why I've understood it's the optimization by the compiler @SyedFarjadZiaZaidi. Why do you ask?

Comment: Because I have seen a couple of posts about problems in debugging in VS.

Comment: And what happens if you set the breakpoint on `string s = "10;` and when the debugger hit it, move to next line with `F10` key? Does it hit the `string t = "Hi";` line?

Comment: @SyedFarjadZiaZaidi Then close it as a duplicate, if not, then I don't think your comments are helpful to me or anyone else!

Comment: @KamilT, yes, if I step  (F10 or F11) then it does hit it but, as soon as I pass it (go to the next line) there is no value for `t`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual studio 2010 debugger don't stop at Breakpoint?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089913/visual-studio-2010-debugger-dont-stop-at-breakpoint)

Comment: Sounds like a pdb issue. Have you tried manually deleting the bin \ obj folders? Also, just double check you aren't running under Release configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you store some debugger-related log in that variable.
You can use the `volatile` keyword, it basically says "Don't you optimize me!" to the compiler:

```
volatile string t = "Hi";  // t won't be optimised.
```

The keyword states that this particular area in memory can be set by some other parties (f.e. another asynchronous code), so the compiler won't optimise it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was thanks to @MikeCheel who suggested I deleted the pdb files. It was then I noticed my debug folder was empty, but my release folder was full of files. Clearly, the issue had to be my configuration settings.

I found out where quite quickly now I knew what to look for:

So, I right click on the solution -> Properties

Under configuration properties, my project was set to Release under Debug.

This fixed it, sadly, my code is asserting every where now so at least I know it's working!